# How can I get rid of this Unauthorized Access exception?

Tags: powershell, pdf, type-conversion

I'm trying to create a script to automate converting pub files to pdf:

```
Function Pub-PDF($f, $p)
{
    $Pub = New-Object -ComObject Publisher.Application
    $Doc = $Pub.Open($f)
    $Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.PbFixedFormatType]::pbFixedFormatTypePDF, $p)
    $Doc.Close()
    [gc]::Collect()
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    $Pub.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Pub)
    Remove-Variable Pub
}

Pub-PDF -f C:\Users\User\Desktop\testFolder\01_afr_mod1_00.pub -p C:\Users\User\Desktop\testFolder
```

This script produces the following error:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsbN5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you are passing in to your -p parameter needs to include a filename. Try something like

```
Pub-PDF -f C:\Users\User\Desktop\testFolder\01_afr_mod1_00.pub -p C:\Users\User\Desktop\testFolder\converted.pdf
```